# Tracing and diagnostics for System.Data.SQLConnection

Tags: .net, sql, debugging

Hi i was wondering if there is away to allow tracing / diagnostics on a SQLConnection via the app.config file much like you can with WCF when you need tracing support (as below)?

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <switches>
      <add name="DataMessagesSwitch" value="0" />
      <add name="TraceLevelSwitch" value="0" />
   </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I'm trying to intercept and log SQL requests from within my application (without needing to create an IDBConnection shim over a SQLConnection to capture the requests as they are executed)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Absolutely insane amount of work to get tracing going :( The ADO.NET team must have forgotten about `System.Diagnostics`.

Comment: I want to ask the same question. Have you found the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Standard approach Microsoft suggests is really complicated and poor designed. Here is the workaround: [Data Access Tracing in .NET (Universal approach)](http://blog.pmunin.com/2014/01/data-access-tracing-in-net-universal.html). The idea is encapsulated wrapping (proxy) all Db access services (DbConnection, DbCommand,...) by a tracer. This works with any DbConnection providers and with Entity Framework as well.

Comment: "really complicated" is putting it mildly. No way I'm going to try to put that in production to get to the bottom of a pressing issue. it seems your (great and general) solution only traces at the  `DbConnection`/`DbCommand` level, so getting closer to the actual network connections (which are pooled and different from `DbConnection` instances) is I guess out of scope?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by actual network connections? tracing network  communication with Db server? For that I believe you can use standard network tracing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, the network connections, in order to trace disconnects. I just tried network tracing, to no avail. Unfortunately nothing that SqlConnection does gets logged, but double checking by directly using sockets showed that tracing was setup correctly.