# Tracing System.Data.SQLConnection (SqlClient)

Tags: debugging

I'm writing a .Net application with db connection and queries.
Using Syste.Data.SqlClient.
I'd like to trace each sql executed by my application, but from an extrnal application.
Is there an API, or some sort of trace I can setup to find each statement passing through the driver?

thanks!
Nava

Comment: I don't want to use sqlProfiler. I was thinking of creating a programed trace for the executed sqls in my app (same as I can write a code profiler using the ICorProfilerCallback interface).

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419772/tracing-and-diagnostics-for-system-data-sqlconnection

Comment: I checked it, but could not make it trace the actual sqls... is it even possible? could be that I'm missing somthing there?

Comment: @Nava: A .NET profiler will not help you at all.

Comment: I understand that, and I gave the .Net profiler as an example of what I want to acomplish, which is a programed trace of the db driver, actualy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard approach Microsoft suggests is really complicated and poor designed. Here is the workaround: [Data Access Tracing in .NET (Universal approach)](http://blog.pmunin.com/2014/01/data-access-tracing-in-net-universal.html). The idea is encapsulated wrapping (proxy) all Db access services (DbConnection, DbCommand,...) by a tracer. This works with any DbConnection providers and with Entity Framework as well.